# Custom Regex format for ######-##

Tags: c#, regex

I am absolutely clueless when it comes to Regex strings. I am trying to create a custom validator on a model using [RegularExpression("myValidator")] How can I create a regex expression to validate the following formats

- ######-##
- ######-#

where # is a number.

Comment: Patterns are `^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}$` and `^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]$`

Comment: Assuming you want a single pattern for both formats, you can use `^\d{6}-\d\d?$`.

Answer (score 0):

- `\d` means digit.
- `{N}` means previous symbol repeated N times

so, basically you want:

```
\d{6}-\d{2}
```

which would match 6 digits, a dash, and 2 more digits.

You can also do:

```
\d{6}-\d{1,2}
```

which would match 6 digits, a dash, and then 1 or 2 more digits, and therefore work for either format you described.

Comment: Did you read the question? Your answer says nothing about `######-#`...

Comment: If the OP cannot figure out `######-#` from the info I provided, they have issues....

Comment: Note that `^` and `$` refer to start and end of string, not line, unless you are using the multiline option. Since the original question referred to a validator for a model, this is presumably for a single string field, in which case accepting e.g. ABC######-# would be incorrect, so the `^` and `$` are needed.